# circleci v2 config - how do we filter by owner in a workflow?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

In the circleci version 1 config, there was the option to specify `owner` as an option in a deployment. An example from the circleci docs ( https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/ ) with `owner: circleci` being the key line:

```
deployment:
  master:
    branch: master
    owner: circleci
    commands:
      - ./deploy_master.sh
```

In version 2 of the config, there is the ability to use filters and tags to specify which branches are built, but I have yet to find (in the docs, or on the interwebs) anything that gives me the same capability.

What I'm trying to achieve is run build and test steps on forks, but only run the deploy steps if the repository owner is the main repo. Quite often people fork using the same branch name - in this case `master` - so having a build fail due to an inability to deploy is counter-intuitive, especially as I would like to use a protected branch in git and only merge commits based on a successful build in a pull request.

I realise we could move to only running builds based on tags being present, but nothing is stopping somebody with a fork also creating a tag in their fork, which puts us back at square one.

**Is anybody aware of how to specify the owner of a repo in the version 2 config?**

An example from the version 2 config document ( https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/ ) in case it helps jog somebodies memory:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  un-tagged-build:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              ignore: /^v.*/
  tagged-build:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
        tags:
          only: /^v.*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

That feature is not available on CircleCI 2.0. You can request it [here](https://circleci.com/ideas/).

As an alternative, you might be able to look for the branch name, say `master`, as well as the `CIRCLE_PR_NUMBER` environment variable. If that variable has any value, then it's a fork of `master` and you shouldn't deploy.

Comment: Thanks - I'll put in a request. Using if statements isn't a good approach though, as there are quite a few steps to making sure our deploy works correctly that would just slow down a build otherwise, and that will be an ugly hack while we wait for the v1 functionality to get put in v2 as well I guess.

Comment: This is critical to making sure some steps don't run on forks... It looks like the feature request was opened here: https://circleci.ideas.aha.io/ideas/CCI-I-356